# Delphi Runtime Error 217 when application is started (Assertion failure (C:\...\tmssoftware\TMS VCL UI Pack\AdvXPVS.pas, line 1536)

Tags: delphi, windows-7, delphi-10.1-berlin, tms

After the upgrade from "TMS ComponentPack" to "TMS VCL UI Pack", the application installed on Windows 7 or windows 8.1, crashes after start with the error RunTime Error 217.

The same application works on windows 10 or windows server 2012

Using EurekaLog, I can see that the specific error is Assertion Failure on AdvXPVS.pas at line 1536 during call procedure LOADDLL

I cannot debug the application becouse of my development platform is installed on windows 10.

```
procedure LoadDLL;
begin
  if DLLLoaded then Exit;

  DLLHandle := LoadLibrary('UXTHEME.DLL');
  if DLLHandle >= 32 then
  begin
    DLLLoaded := True;

    @OpenThemeDataForDpi := GetProcAddress(DLLHandle,'OpenThemeDataForDpi');
    Assert(@OpenThemeDataForDpi <> nil);

    //********************************************************* 
    // LINE 1536 START FROM HERE 
    //********************************************************* 
    @OpenThemeData := GetProcAddress(DLLHandle,'OpenThemeData');
    Assert(@OpenThemeData <> nil);

    @CloseThemeData := GetProcAddress(DLLHandle,'CloseThemeData');
    Assert(@CloseThemeData <> nil);

    @DrawThemeBackground := GetProcAddress(DLLHandle,'DrawThemeBackground');
    Assert(@DrawThemeBackground <> nil);


    ...
    ...

    @EnableTheming := GetProcAddress(DLLHandle,'EnableTheming');
    Assert(@EnableTheming <> nil);
  end
  else
  begin
    DLLLoaded := False;
    { Error: UXTHEME.DLL could not be loaded !! }
  end;

end;
```

Assembler Information:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Base Address: $1012000, Allocation Base: $400000, Region Size: 10563584
; Allocation Protect: PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY, Protect: PAGE_EXECUTE_READ
; State: MEM_COMMIT, Type: MEM_IMAGE
; 
;
; AdvXPVS.LoadDLL (Line=0 - Offset=33)
; ------------------------------------
01012459  8903            MOV  [EBX], EAX
0101245B  833B20          CMP  DWORD PTR [EBX], $20
0101245E  0F825F080000    JB   +$085F                  ; ($01012CC3) AdvXPVS.LoadDLL (Line=0)
01012464  C605CC26A60101  MOV  BYTE PTR [$01A626CC], 1
0101246B  68E82C0101      PUSH $01012CE8               ; ($01012CE8) AdvXPVS.LoadDLL (Line=0) Data as ANSI: 'O'; Data as UNICODE: 'OpenThemeDataFor...' AdvXPVS.LoadDLL (Line=0)
01012470  8B03            MOV  EAX, [EBX]
01012472  50              PUSH EAX
01012473  E864DE40FF      CALL -$BF219C                ; ($004202DC) Winapi.GetProcAddress
01012478  8BF0            MOV  ESI, EAX
0101247A  8935C844BA01    MOV  [$01BA44C8], ESI
01012480  85F6            TEST ESI, ESI
01012482  7514            JNZ  +$14                    ; ($01012498) AdvXPVS.LoadDLL (Line=0)
01012484  B900060000      MOV  ECX, $00000600
01012489  BA1C2D0101      MOV  EDX, $01012D1C          ; ($01012D1C) AdvXPVS.LoadDLL (Line=0) UNICODE: 'C:\Users\Gianluca\Documents\tmssoftware\TMS VCL UI Pack\AdvXPVS.pas' AdvXPVS.LoadDLL (Line=0)
0101248E  B8B02D0101      MOV  EAX, $01012DB0          ; ($01012DB0) AdvXPVS.LoadDLL (Line=0) UNICODE: 'Assertion failure' AdvXPVS.LoadDLL (Line=0)
;
; Line=0 - Offset=91
; ------------------
01012493  E800A53FFF      CALL -$C05B00                ; ($0040C998) System._Assert  ; <-- EXCEPTION
01012498  68D42D0101      PUSH $01012DD4               ; ($01012DD4) AdvXPVS.LoadDLL (Line=0) Data as ANSI: 'O'; Data as UNICODE: 'OpenThemeData' AdvXPVS.LoadDLL (Line=0)
0101249D  8B03            MOV  EAX, [EBX]
0101249F  50              PUSH EAX
010124A0  E837DE40FF      CALL -$BF21C9                ; ($004202DC) Winapi.GetProcAddress
010124A5  8BF0            MOV  ESI, EAX
010124A7  8935CC44BA01    MOV  [$01BA44CC], ESI
010124AD  85F6            TEST ESI, ESI
010124AF  7514            JNZ  +$14                    ; ($010124C5) AdvXPVS.LoadDLL (Line=0)
010124B1  B903060000      MOV  ECX, $00000603
010124B6  BA1C2D0101      MOV  EDX, $01012D1C          ; ($01012D1C) AdvXPVS.LoadDLL (Line=0) UNICODE: 'C:\Users\Gianluca\Documents\tmssoftware\TMS VCL UI Pack\AdvXPVS.pas' AdvXPVS.LoadDLL (Line=0)
010124BB  B8B02D0101      MOV  EAX, $01012DB0          ; ($01012DB0) AdvXPVS.LoadDLL (Line=0) UNICODE: 'Assertion failure' AdvXPVS.LoadDLL (Line=0)
010124C0  E8D3A43FFF      CALL -$C05B2D                ; ($0040C998) System._Assert
010124C5  68F02D0101      PUSH $01012DF0               ; ($01012DF0) AdvXPVS.LoadDLL (Line=0) Data as ANSI: 'C'; Data as UNICODE: 'CloseThemeData' AdvXPVS.LoadDLL (Line=0)
010124CA  8B03            MOV  EAX, [EBX]
010124CC  50              PUSH EAX
010124CD  E80ADE40FF      CALL -$BF21F6                ; ($004202DC) Winapi.GetProcAddress
```

Call Stack Information:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Methods |Details|Stack   |Address |Module           |Offset  |Source       |Unit     |Class|Procedure/Method   |Line               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|*Exception Thread: ID=596; Parent=0; Priority=0                                                                                    |
|Class=; Name=MAIN                                                                                                                  |
|DeadLock=0; Wait Chain=                                                                                                            |
|Comment=                                                                                                                           |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|7FFFFFFE|03     |00000000|01012493|testxHairPlus.exe|00C12493|AdvXPVS.pas  |AdvXPVS  |     |LoadDLL            |                   |
|00000060|03     |0018FF34|019F4A28|testxHairPlus.exe|015F4A28|AdvXPVS.pas  |AdvXPVS  |     |Initialization     |                   |
|00000060|03     |0018FF3C|0040C512|testxHairPlus.exe|0000C512|System.pas   |System   |     |InitUnits          |                   |
|00000060|03     |0018FF60|0040C57B|testxHairPlus.exe|0000C57B|System.pas   |System   |     |_StartExe          |                   |
|00000020|03     |0018FF64|004147CE|testxHairPlus.exe|000147CE|SysInit.pas  |SysInit  |     |_InitExe           |                   |
|00004020|03     |0018FF6C|01A2435F|testxHairPlus.exe|0162435F|xHairPlus.pas|xHairPlus|     |Initialization     |                   |
|7FFF7FFE|03     |0018FF84|75027C02|kernel32.dll     |00017C02|KERNEL32.DLL |KERNEL32 |     |BaseThreadInitThunk|                   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: `if DLLHandle >= 32 then` should be `if DLLHandle <> 0 then`. The "magic" value 32 only applies to `ShellExecute()`, not to `LoadLibrary()`. As for the assert, it doesn't make sense for `GetProcAddress("OpenThemeData")` to fail if `uxtheme.dll` is successfully loaded. What does `GetLastError()` say when `GetProcAddress()` fails? This code shouldn't be using assert like this, it should just set `DLLLoaded := False;` on failure and exit normally.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The application crashes with "Runtime error 217"  GetLastError() code is EAssertionFailed

Comment: Delphi includes remote debugging, http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Overview_of_Remote_Debugging

Comment: @GianlucaColombo That is not what I asked. `EAssertionFailed` is an exception raised by `assert()`. `GetLastError()` returns a Win32 error code, not raise an exception. Please modify the code to call `GetLastError()` *immediately* after `GetProcAddress()` fails and before calling `assert()`, what does `GetLastError()` actually return? `@OpenThemeData := GetProcAddress(DLLHandle,'OpenThemeData'); if @OpenThemeData = nil then begin {what does GetLastError() report here?} end; Assert(@OpenThemeData <> nil);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes we get errors with line numbers off by one. In your case `Assert(@OpenThemeDataForDpi <> nil);` is failing because `OpenThemeDataForDpi` needs at least Windows 10 1703. As workaround you can write your own version which just ignores `dpi` argument and calls standard `OpenThemeData`, then when you get `nil` pointer set it to your implementation.